# Block any other domains from using my server

Tags: wordpress, security, apache2, hacking

Someone has set their domain to use my server. It's not a mirror, the database and everything works and updates with mine. He's basically stealing my content, and he's showing up on google instead of me.

He serves all my content with his own domains, Currently I denying stealer with cloudflare `Under Attack Mode`

I try Block IP with `.htaccess` & wordpress firewall plugins but these not stop him. (stealer domain viewers also show in my analytic)

Is there a way to make it so my server will only respond to requests from my domain?

I'm hosting Wordpress with LAMP stack on Ubuntu 16.04 (OVH VPS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will be helpful for others. This is how I stop stealer with javascript

```
var x = location.hostname;
if ( x != 'www.example.com'){
window.location.replace("https://www.example.com");
}
```

Then use this [javascriptobfuscator](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx) to encrypt the script and put on top of header file.

Because of encryption domain name not replaceable (In my case stealer use nginx to change domain name)

If anyone need server side solution

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] != "www.example.com"){
    if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] != "example.com"){
        echo "<script>window.location.replace(\"https://www.example.com/\")</script>";
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use JavaScript when you could issue a server side redirect?  Search engines may not honor that JavaScript redirect.

Comment: In my case every request made with my domain then stealer use my source code for his domains, so server side cannot detect his domain. Even without encryption JavaScript not work for me

Comment: If it is served by your server it can be detected by your server.  Your server side version is the one that should be issuing the resurrect.  I can see the case for a js only solution if they are using a reverse proxy to mirror your site.

Answer (score 3):

Your Apache is improperly configured. Apache should only respond to properly configured domains. Somehow, your Apache is configured to respond to *any* domain, which is your problem.

Check your config for something like this in the `VirtualHost` block

```
ServerAlias *
```

That could be your problem, as Apache will now serve up any domain for that virtual host. Instead, it should look something like

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.yourdomain.com
    ServerAlias yourdomain.com
    ...
</virtualHost>
```

Another solution is to make their domain have its own config that returns a 404 (make sure this config loads first)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName   hijackdomain.com
    ServerAlias  www.hijackdomain.com
    Redirect 404 /
    ErrorDocument 404 "Page Not Found"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The first virtual host in Apache always matches all host names regardless of whether it contains the wildcard server alias.   I always recommend creating a first default virtual host that always returns 404 errors.